# Source Code shows for ASP.NET web page

Tags: asp.net, iis, web

I have a simple .aspx file that I want to run in my browser. I have installed IIS, along with all ASP.NET features, on my local machine. I am using USBWEBSERVER as a server to display my web pages.

When I put in the path of the file of my of web page (.aspx file), just like I do with all my PHP pages, I get the source code (instead of the GUI).

How can I set this up so .aspx pages will work on my machine?

Comment: What port are you running the ASP.NET site on?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/Test/WebForm1.aspx

Comment: Can USBWEBSERVER host asp .net websites? Seems to be php only http://www.usbwebserver.net/en/index.php

Comment: I would assume but I am not sure. I have USBWEBSERVER so I can have it on my local machine instead of having a web server

Comment: USBWEBSERVER will not work for ASP.NET pages. So how do you all code ASP.NET and have a temporary webserver like USBWEBSERVER for testing purposes?

Comment: There are many service providers for .net hosting, just pick one. Some allow free hosting (with limited features). I use https://appharbor.com/ for some personal projects. Just push your code through source control (git, subversion, etc.), then it get's built and deployed for you. Others you can just xcopy the binaries and pages via ftp or other means.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to get a web server that supports ASP.NET. Right now, there's IIS Express, which is free and can host a multitude of technologies:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1038

Comment: I have it working on my localhost. One questions tho. To run my web page do I only have to include WebForm1.aspx and WebForm1.aspx.vb for the page to run? because I am getting errors saying that I can inherit a certain page